# Give a linechart XAxis academic month order

Tags: javafx, linechart

I have created a simple line chart where I compare the current years values to past years (could be an average or not).

[image: Example of the basic chart]

The issue is that as this is for UK Academic purposes I want the months to run from June through to June the following year.

Currently my code looks like:

```
xAxis.setLabel("Date/Month");
    xAxis.setTickLabelRotation(90);

    xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
    xAxis.setLowerBound(1);
    xAxis.setUpperBound(12);
    xAxis.setTickUnit(1.0);

    xAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<Number>() {

        @Override
        public String toString(Number month) {
            logger.debug("Converting " + month);
            return new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month.intValue()-1];
        }

        @Override
        public Number fromString(String string) {
            try {
                Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").parse(string);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(date);
                return cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                logger.error("Parse Exception");
            }
            return  0;
        }

    });


    yAxis.setLabel("Units");
```

where the series are created using a simple function:

```
    private XYChart.Series createSeries(String name, List<AccountUtilities> data) {
    XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
    series.setName(name);
    for (AccountUtilities utility : data) {
        String[] dateParts = utility.getStartdate().split("-");
        Double dateCode = Double.valueOf(dateParts[1]);
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data( dateCode , utility.getGasunits()));
    }
    return series;
}
```

My current thought is that I can reindex the months as June = 1, July = 2 etc. to get the values into the chart in the correct order and then decode them into their 'correct' values June = 6 when I get setTickLabelFormatter to do its thing but this seems a long way around.

Is there a nifty feature of javafx charting that I'm missing?

Current resources used:

- [javafx line chart with date axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987823/javafx-line-chart-with-date-axis)
- [How to perform big numbers on axis (for example, 10^3 format) in chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257787/how-to-perform-big-numbers-on-axis-for-example-103-format-in-chart?lq=1)

Comment: Any reason why you are still using the long outdated and poorly designed classes `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`? [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is so much nicer to work with. It seems to me you want [`Month.getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)).

Comment: Because my knowledge is circa 2000 and I'm getting back up to date?    Thanks for the knowledge - I'll update.

Comment: @OleV.V.   Thanks again for the advice.  Hopefully my updated answer below is more in keeping with current best practice.

Comment: It certainly is (+1). This should be helpful to future readers, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So I followed my initial thought process and although it was more complicated than I initially thought with any offset that wasn't 6 months the following works for both 6 and 8.
The following method reorders Jan(1) to Dec(12) to the offsetted order e.g.   Jun(1) to May(12) so the data appears in the desired order in the chart.

```
private Double getAcademicMonth(String baseDate) {
    Integer dateCode = Integer.valueOf(baseDate);

    //Any month greater than the accounting start month gets shifted by six.
    if (dateCode > offset) { dateCode = dateCode - offset; }
    else { dateCode = dateCode + (12-offset); }

    return dateCode;
}
```

I then required a means of converting the months back on the fly when the chart was drawn so I got the correct month labels, which was achieved with setTickLabelFormatter

```
    //We have to set tick label formatter now once the offset has been retrieved.
    xAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<Number>() {

        @Override
        public String toString(Number month) {

            //Shift our months to account for the accounting start month
            int dateCode = month.intValue();
            if (dateCode <= (12 - offset) ) { dateCode = dateCode + offset; }
            else { dateCode = dateCode - (12-offset); }

            Month day = Month.of(dateCode);
            return day.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH);

        }

        @Override
        public Number fromString(String string) {
          DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
          TemporalAccessor accessor = parser.parse(string);
          return accessor.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR);
        }

    });
```

[image: The end result with additional data series.]

Comment: hmm ... what's the type of the xAxis? Wouldn't a Category axis suit your needs? If not, there are DateAxis out in the wild that allow setting the start in terms of a LocalDate

Comment: That was the knowledge I was looking for. Thanks.  TBH this works pretty well for my purposes for now.